# Material Components with Laravel

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, material-components, material-components-web

As per the documentation of Google Material Components, I am unable to find a way to integrate it with **Laravel**. The steps mentioned there to configure the webpack are mentioned however I am unable to find a suitable way to put it in Laravel Mix.

So the question is how to integrate google material components(not the lite version) into Laravel project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Laravel Mix, integration of Material Components is easier than with plain Webpack config.

First, install default Laravel project's Node dependencies, and make sure that you have `node-sass` and `sass-loader` installed, and, of course, add `material-components-web`:

```
npm i
npm i node-sass sass-loader -D
npm i material-components-web -S
```

Then, assuming that you have an `app.js` in `resources/assets/scripts` folder  and `app.scss` in `resources/assets/sass` folder, your `webpack.mix.js` should look something like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix')

mix
.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {
  includePaths: ['node_modules']
})
```

Then, in `app.js` and `app.scss` you import ES2015 and Sass respectively the same way as described in [MDC Web documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/#using-mdc-web-with-es2015-and-sass).

Here I described how to install Vanilla JS project. If you're interested in Vue.js, then you can add [Vue.js wrapper for MDC-Web](https://stasson.github.io/vue-mdc-adapter) (Vue MDC Adapter):

```
npm i vue-mdc-adapter -S
```

Then, use it as described in [Vue MDC Adapter documentation](https://stasson.github.io/vue-mdc-adapter/#/docs/getting-started).

Comment: I have tried the way you described but when using the components in Vue files it's giving not found package error even if the package is still there.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without looking at the code. Any GitHub repo or a link with reproduction?